# Wordpress Scroll using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, event-listener

Have a site that needs the page to move with the arrow keys we have the left/right functioning correctly but the up & down arrows are not moving through the page sections as desired. Below is the script and the link to the dev site.

site is http://bobbyd16.sg-host.com/

```
$('#leftScroll img').click(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 37; // 
    $("#leftScroll img").trigger(e); 
    
})

$('#leftScroll img').click(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 38; // 
    $("#leftScroll img").trigger(e); 
    
})

$('#rightScroll img').click(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 39; // 
    $("#leftScroll img").trigger(e);
})

$('#rightScroll img').click(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 40; // 
    $("#leftScroll img").trigger(e);
})
```

Comment: This code only show click event not key event.

Comment: Ah I gotcha. Sorry , still learning jquery/js . Any suggestion on what to add to make this fuction?